# What does Uninitialized mean in smartgit?

Tags: git, smartgit

I have some files that Uninitialized is written in state column for them in smartgit.

What does it mean and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full documentation for this:

http://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG070/Directory+Tree+and+File+Table

---

In your case ***`Uninitialized`*** means that you have Uninitialized sub-modules.
You need to initialize and update them.

```
# init the submodule
git submodule <name> init

# update the submodule
git submodule update
```

---

### ***`What is this submodule?`***

If you don't have a clue what is submodule read this very detailed blog post from atlassian.

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/03/git-submodules-workflows-tips/

Comment: Using SmartGit, you can initialize a submodule using **Remote|Submodule|Initialize**. The dialog also provides a **Pull** option which corresponds to the `git submodule update`